# Display top 10 words in a CSV file

Tags: java, sorting, csv, google-cloud-storage

I have CSV file which i have stored in Google cloud storage . I am reading this CSV file and building a tree map for each occurrence of the words . Is there way i can sort and display only top 10 words in the file ?

Here's my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GoogleCloudStorageServlet extends HttpServlet {
   public static final String BUCKETNAME = "bigdata";
   public static final String FILENAME = "Railways.csv";

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world from java");
    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
    GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, FILENAME);
    GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
        .mimeType("text/html")
        .acl("public-read")
        .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value")
        .build();

    GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Channels.newWriter(writeChannel, "UTF8"));

    GcsInputChannel readChannel = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    try {
      readChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(filename, 0);
      reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));
      String line;
      TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

          String[] post = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

          String[] words = post[1].split("[ \n\t\r.,;:!?(){}]");

          for (int counter = 0; counter < words.length; counter++) {
              String key = words[counter].toLowerCase(); // remove .toLowerCase for Case Sensitive result.
              if (key.length() > 0) {
                  if (map.get(key) == null) {
                      map.put(key, 1);
                  }
                  else {
                      int value = map.get(key).intValue();
                      value++;
                      map.put(key, value);
                  }
              }
           }

          //Display only top 10 words in the file
    }


    } finally {
      if (reader != null) { reader.close(); }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to get top 10 words or how to display them?

Comment: @pgiecek Yes,Thats my question .

Comment: Ok. ;-) Which one? 1) How to get top 10 words or 2) How to display the result. Or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to calculate top 10 words in a CSV file depends on the size of the file.

1. Small files (can be stored in a memory)

   In case of a small file, you can use some kind of a collection optimised for your case (e.g. [Multiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) mentioned by Bill Lin) or perform calculation on your own.

   ```
   Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
       for (String word : words) {
       Integer count = counts.get(word);
       if (count == null) {
           counts.put(word, 1);
       } else {
          counts.put(word, count + 1);
       }
   }
   ```

   Such a computation can be handled within a scope of a single request if the file is really small.
2. Medium/large size files

   In case of medium or large size files, you may exceed the request limit (60s) and may also run out of available memory. It would not be very efficient either. You need a different approach.

   Try to look at [MapReduce for App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/dataprocessing/).

   > MapReduce is a programming model for processing large amounts of data in a parallel and distributed fashion. It is useful for large, long-running jobs that cannot be handled within the scope of a single request.

The way to display your results depends on your processing mode.

1. Synchronous

   If your calculation is synchronous, you can display your results directly from Servlet via passed response object.

   ```
   HttpServletResponse#getWriter()
   ```
2. Asynchronous

   In case of asynchronous calculation, you need to store your results somewhere (e.g. Datastore) and display them on demand

Comment: How do i sort them by values ? So that i can display only top 10 ?

Comment: Provided that you used the simplest approach based on the `Map`, you can sort it by means of `Collections#sort(List, Comparator)`, where the first parameter is map's entry set converted to `List` and the second is your custom comparator using entry's value. Anyway keep in mind that this solution as a whole is for really small files and you do not care of efficiency much.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you use 
Multiset  and Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained